# How to find count of one column based on two columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

How I can get last column based on the "competition" and "user" columns? the following query gives error!

```html
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS countofcomments
FROM k
GROUP BY competition, user
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean, "how to *find* the count of one column based on two columns?"

Comment: @Alex Thanks for letting me know! I fixed it. I just have 3 days until due of the workshop paper and still does not have proper data to run data analysis! My brain stopped working

Comment: I don't understand what comments is supposed to contain. Is it a number, a string or is it a table with an array of comments?  What is your table structure for this?

Comment: we do not need the content of comment. for example here we see for competition A user Hani there are 2 comments! actually I want to calculate the number of rows for competition A user Hani and create new column with the name "count of comment" and insert 2 there.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is that a good practice you trying to achieve, On considering the result set you can try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #Example(
       [competition]      [nvarchar](50)   NULL,       
       [user]   [nvarchar](50)   NULL,
       [comments]   nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
)
GO

INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('INDIA','CHENNAI','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('INDIA','KOCHI','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('INDIA','BANGLORE','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('INDIA','HYDERABAD','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('US','MAIAMI','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('US','SANFRANC','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('US','MOUNT','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('US','LOSANGELS','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('UK','MANCHESTER','ssss')
INSERT   #Example  ([competition],[user],  [comments])   VALUES ('UK','CHELSEA','ssss')

SELECT * from (
SELECT * FROM #Example 
) tab1 join 

(
SELECT [competition] , count([comments] )count FROM #Example
group by [competition]
) tab2 on tab1.[competition]= tab2.[competition]


DROP table #Example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window function:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY competition, user) as [Count of comments]
FROM k
```